# Вылезает ошибка, не могу понять почему

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, бот, discord.py

Вот код, из за него длинная ошибка(написал ошибку в конце)

```
@client.command()
async def время(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed( title = "Время", colour = discord.Colour.red(), url ='https://time100.ru/' )

    emb.set_author( name = client.user.name, icon_url = client.user.avatar )
    emb.set_footer( text = ctx.authorm.name, icon_url = ctx.authoe.avatar_url )
    emb.set_image(url = "https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190118/ourmid/pngtree-vector-clock-icon-png-image_323861.jpg")
    emb.set_thumbnail( url = 'https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190114/ourmid/pngtree-vector-clock-icon-png-image_313133.jpg')


    now_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    emb.add_field( name = 'Time', value = 'Time: {}'.format(now_date) )

    await ctx.send( embed = emb )
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'authorm'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибки нужно читать снизу вверх.
'Context' не  имеет атрибута 'authorm' 
Это `emb.set_footer( text = ctx.authorm.name, icon_url = ctx.authoe.avatar_url )` измени на `emb.set_footer( text = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url )`